# Insert object into std::deque that does not allow copy constructor

Tags: c++, deque

Im using a `std::deque` to hold some objects, and it works great as long as I can add new elements with `deque.emplace_front`. However, now I want to replace an element of the deque with an already existing object. When I try to do the following

```
auto it = mydeque.begin();
++it;
mydeque.insert(it, object);
mydeque.erase(it);
```

I get an error because my object does not allow copying. How can I get around this issue?

EDIT:

- My object is of type `hp::DoFHandler<dim>`, documented here: https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/classhp_1_1DoFHandler.html.
- The reason I can not use `emplace` is because this method constructs a new object, while I want to insert my existing one.
- I could create a minimal working example, but since Im using the FEM framework https://www.dealii.org/, it would require either installing it or downloading a Docker image.

Comment: For completeness you should show a [mcve]

Comment: Does the object support copy assignment?

Comment: If you’re successfully using `emplace_front` for front insertion, why not use `emplace` for middle insertion?

Comment: `std::deque` has an `emplace` function that works just like `insert` does, but allowing you to use the emplace mechanics.  Also, Why not just reassign the object, i.e, `*it = std::move(object)`?

Comment: The `emplace` method creates a new object, while I want to insert an existing one. Reassigning the object might work, I didn't know about that possibility.

Comment: You can still use `emplace` or `insert` with an existing object by wrapping it with `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Only if the type is movable.

Comment: @eerorika: I'm not sure what "insert an existing object" could possibly mean for a type that is non-moveable.

Comment: @BenVoigt It would mean something that cannot be done.

Comment: @eerorika: Then Nathan's suggestion of `emplace` or `insert` combined with `std::move` seems to cover all cases -- it moves if that is possible, and errors if the necessary operation cannot be done.

Comment: @BenVoigt  When the goal is to have an element inside the container, error does not achieve that goal.

Comment: @eerorika: It correctly tells the programmer what you wrote in your comment "that cannot be done" and in your answer "Otherwise you cannot insert a pre-existing object"

Comment: If you need to hold non-movable, non-copyable object in a container, first create the object in a `unique_ptr`, and then put the `unique_ptr` smarter pointer object into the container.  If the object is owned elsewhere, and you are careful about the lifespan of that object, you could hold a raw pointer to the object in the container.

Answer (score 4):

> The reason I can not use emplace is because this method constructs a new object, while I want to insert my existing one.

The element of a container is always a distinct object. If you insert an existing object, then the object must be copied or moved.

> I get an error because my object does not allow copying. How can I get around this issue?

If the type allows moving, then you can use `std::move`. Othewise, you cannot insert a pre-existing object into the container.

---

Some XY-solutions for non-movable types:

- Avoid the problem by creating the object within the container initially, using `emplace`.
- Use indirection. Instead of storing `hp::DoFHandler<dim>` objects in the container, rather store something that refers to such object like a pointer for example. This approach has the drawback of having to ensure that the lifetime of the pointer doesn't exceed the lifetime of the pointed object. Using shared ownership (`std::shared_ptr`) is an easy way to make sure of that, but it has other potential drawbacks.